# automatically generate instances of a model when a different one is created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I really didn't know how to phrase the question better but here goes:

Lets say i have 2 models

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :record 
end
```

I want a way to make sure that every time a new record instance is created 2 new roles are created automatically by the system for that record.

each `role` will have a `name`, `record_id`, `Boolean called edit` and `Boolean called review`.

so if i create a `record` called `Hello` and it has an ID `1` then the system should create these 2 new roles at the same time:

Role 1: `name: Hello edit`, `record_id: 1`, `edit: true`, `review: false`

Role 2: `name: Hello review`, `record_id: 1`, `edit: false`, `review: true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord callbacks to the rescue:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_roles

  def create_roles
    Role.create :name => "Hello edit", :record_id => self.id, :edit => true, :review => false
    Role.create :name => "Hello review", :record_id => self.id, :edit => false, :review => true
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, lets say the relationship between the roles and record became a hmabt relationship, how would you add the association between the two once you have created the new roles? roles will belong to many records that have the same ``secondary_id`` (which is really just different versions of the same record but are separate entities in the DB). Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  after_create :add_roles

  def add_roles
    roles.create [
      {:name => "Hello edit", :edit => true, :review => false},
      {:name => "Hello review", :edit => false, :review => true}]
  end
end
```